# How to swipe left or right to push or pop ViewContrller in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to swipe in my app to push or pop ViewControllers , I know I can add a swipe gesture to that.
But When I swipe the screen ,I want the current ViewController followed with my swipe gesture ,and next ViewController pushes in just with the swipe. How can I do this,Thank you!

Comment: The perfect working solution with code and explanation:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/32990248/988169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with `UINavigationController`; you'll have to build your own navigation controller (should be pretty easy) that incorporates a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

EDIT for iOS 7: You'll probably want to use a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 1):

Gesture recognizers have action methods just like buttons. Just put this in the action method:

```
NextViewController *next = [[NextViewController alloc] init ....];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
```

Comment: I know that. But I want the ViewController can move with my finger

Comment: @lixiaoyu, well, then that's not a "push" or "pop" in the usual sense, and you need to do it with a pan rather than a swipe, because a swipe is a discrete gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Read about gesture recognizers. You can create them and add it on objects. 
For example

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                         action:@selector(longPress:)];
longTap.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:longTap];
```

Here I have created LongPress recognizer and added it on my cell. If I will longpress(1.0 sec) on my cell, it will call selector(longPress:). In long press I can make any code.

```
-(void)longPress : (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)rec {
   if (rec.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
   NSLog (@"I've longPressed");
   }
}
```

You can use different recognizers by the same way.

About push and pop. They are methods of Navigation controller.
Push - goes forward, on controller which you shows him;

```
NextController *goNext = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:goNext animated:YES];
```

it will go to the NextController.
Pop - backs to the previous controller.

Here you don't need to show the previous controller. Just say to navController back

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```