# Swipe to go back only works on edge of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard, ios9

My swipe to go back feature works but only works on the edge of the screen.  How can I have it work from anywhere on the screen?

Comment: Please do share some code. Also what UIGestureRecognizer you are using? and what state? PLEASE CODE !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple says [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/interactivePopGestureRecognizer) :

> **interactivePopGestureRecognizer**
>
> The gesture recognizer responsible for popping the top view controller
>   off the navigation stack. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) UIGestureRecognizer
>   *interactivePopGestureRecognizer
>
> The navigation controller installs this gesture recognizer on its view
>   and uses it to pop the topmost view controller off the navigation
>   stack. You can use this property to retrieve the gesture recognizer
>   and tie it to the behavior of other gesture recognizers in your user
>   interface. When tying your gesture recognizers together, make sure
>   they recognize their gestures simultaneously to ensure that your
>   gesture recognizers are given a chance to handle the event.

So [SloppySwiper](http://github.com/fastred/SloppySwiper) library customise the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Check out the library [SloppySwiper](http://github.com/fastred/SloppySwiper), which achieves this by using UIPanGestureRecognizer and by recreating the default animation.

`SloppySwiper:-` UINavigationController delegate that allows swipe back gesture to be started from anywhere on the screen like instagram.

**Usage** of this library can be found [here](http://github.com/fastred/SloppySwiper#usage).

**Cocoapods**:- pod "SloppySwiper"

I test this library on ios7 and above. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 22):

It's actually quite easy to do on the `UINavigationController` subclass without any intervention into every `UIViewController` subclass pushed. Also respecting built-in swipe-from-edge state (so when it's disabled intentionally, the new gesture is disabled as well):

```swift
import UIKit

class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupFullWidthBackGesture()
    }

    private lazy var fullWidthBackGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    private func setupFullWidthBackGesture() {
        // The trick here is to wire up our full-width `fullWidthBackGestureRecognizer` to execute the same handler as
        // the system `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`. That's done by assigning the same "targets" (effectively
        // object and selector) of the system one to our gesture recognizer.
        guard
            let interactivePopGestureRecognizer = interactivePopGestureRecognizer,
            let targets = interactivePopGestureRecognizer.value(forKey: "targets")
        else {
            return
        }

        fullWidthBackGestureRecognizer.setValue(targets, forKey: "targets")
        fullWidthBackGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(fullWidthBackGestureRecognizer)
    }
}

extension NavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        let isSystemSwipeToBackEnabled = interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled == true
        let isThereStackedViewControllers = viewControllers.count > 1
        return isSystemSwipeToBackEnabled && isThereStackedViewControllers
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. How would you avoid `fullWidthBackGestureRecognizer` taking precedence over other recognizers? For instance, the recognizers for `UIContextualAction` are ignored completely while using this method. They (recognizers of the tableview) are also not directly accessible / it's a private API... thus, we can't really use them in the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods of the navigation controller. Any clues on what to do? Otherwise it works great, thanks!

Comment: Vertical scrolling not working with this solution.

Comment: Sweettttttttt!!!!!! AWESOME answer! I had a couple of implementations of this before from somewhere on Github, but those are having issues. I haven't tested this thought with scrollViews.

Comment: Does anyone happen to know how to implement this in SwiftUI? The NavigationLink in SwiftUI only lets you swipe back on the edges as well.

Answer (score -2):

Swipe to go back is default behavior of pushed/showed view controllers. It works from left edge of the screen (by default). If you want to swipe back from any part of the screen, you should add UISwipeGestureRecognizer to your view:
    `let swipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didSwipe:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer)`

Comment: what do I have to add in the didSwipe function?

Comment: self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

Comment: it works but I dont have the ability to control the slide like I do from the edge of the screen?

Comment: Ok so what you want is UIPanGestureRecognizer with custom transition between view controllers. Here you can find good answer with example how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22244990/5402342