# UINavigationBar - right bar Image fade transition

Tags: objective-c, swift

[image]

Can I know what is the function called during the swipe back, and anyone know how to achieve the right bar image fade when swiping back from pushviewcontroller?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914006/swipe-to-go-back-only-works-on-edge-of-screen/32990248#32990248

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244688/navigation-pop-view-when-swipe-right-like-instagram-iphone-app-how-i-achieve-thi/22247976#22247976

Comment: Hi Spynet, Thanks for the answers, I'm using LargeTitle navigationbar, so I found that the right bar image alpha is faded during the swipe back, I have tried to set the alpha at viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, but it doesn't looks like the example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swipe to go back only works on edge of screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914006/swipe-to-go-back-only-works-on-edge-of-screen)

Comment: Hi Damon, is there any function that will be called continuously while swiping back without letting go our finger.